# Using Cloudflare reverse proxy for scripts injected after load

Tags: reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I followed the [following tutorial](https://github.com/Darkseal/CORSflare) to create a service worker on Cloudlfare that will serve as a reverse proxy.

The goal is to embed a webpage (not pre-defined) into an iFrame.

It works on page load, however, there is no way of modifying links that are injected by javascript after load.

As a result, links are loaded at the base path.

```
/path -> myproxy.cloudflare.com/path [BAD] 
/path -> myproxy.cloudflare.com?link=query_domain.com/path [What I want]
```

Any ideas on how to rewrite these URl's?